# How to get the output of the last but one layer of the Vision transformer using the hugging face implementation?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am trying to use the huggingface implementation of the vision transformer to get the feature vector of the last but one dense layer

Comment: You might want to add a bit more detail to the post!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get information from the second last layer, you need to `output_hidden_states=True`. Here is an example in my context:

```
configBert = BertConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', output_hidden_states=True, num_labels=NUM_LABELS)
modelBert = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', config=configBert)
```